# How can I convert CT Nifti Files to Hounsfield Units?

Tags: python-3.x, normalize, medical-imaging, nifti

What is the correct way to convert CT scan nifti files to Hounsfield units? My code is as follows:

```py
path = 'input/volume/volume-0.nii'
img_obj = nib.load(path)
img_data = img_obj.get_fdata()

slope = img_obj.dataobj.slope
intercept = img_obj.dataobj.inter

img_data[img_data >= 1200] = 0 #trying to remove bone area
images = slope * img_data.astype(np.float32)
hu_images = images + intercept
```

But when I try to normalize this hu converted image to [0,1], it yields a black image.

Answer (score 0):

`nib.get_fdata()` should already scale your data if the corresponding header fields are set correctly. For an explanation, see [this nipy article](https://nipy.org/nibabel/nifti_images.html#data-scaling).

Note that if you're trying to set high HU densities to 0 (with `img_data[img_data >= 1200] = 0`), you're giving it the same density as water. What you probably want is to set it to air density (HU -1,000).

In order to scale the image to `[0, 1]` you could use:

```py
from skimage.exposure import rescale_intensity

rescale_intensity(img_data, in_range='image', out_range=(0., 1.))
```

Comment: Thank You. Isn't the HU intensity corresponding to the bone area in CT scan is HU 1200+?

Comment: Cortical bone (the outmost part of the bone) can reach densities >1,000 HU, but there may be physical conditions with reduced bone density. Trabecular bone on the other hand can be closer to the 300 – 800 HU range.